# how to convert plain text into html text in android?

Tags: android, textview

I am uploading the text to server, i just want to upload those string in html format
example

input:

Do you know the relation between two eyes...???
They never see each other... BUT

1. They blink together.
2. They move together.
3. They cry together.
4. They see together.
5. They sleep together.
   They share a very deep bonded relationship...

However, when they see a pretty woman, one will blink and another will not...

```
            sendtext = adding_textjoke.getText().toString();


            //String htmlString = Html.toHtml(sendtext);

            String str = "(?i)\\b((?:https?://|www\\d{0,3}[.]|[a-z0-9.\\-]+[.][a-z]{2,4}/)(?:[^\\s()<>]+|\\(([^\\s()<>]+|(\\([^\\s()<>]+\\)))*\\))+(?:\\(([^\\s()<>]+|(\\([^\\s()<>]+\\)))*\\)|[^\\s`!()\\[\\]{};:\'\".,<>?«»“”‘’]))";
            Pattern patt = Pattern.compile(str);
            Matcher matcher = patt.matcher(sendtext);
            sendtext = matcher.replaceAll("<a href=\"$1\">$1</a>");
            System.out.println(sendtext);
            Log.e("sendtext", sendtext);
            new AddJokesTask().execute(sendtext);
```

How to do this in android?

Comment: show the code you have tried so far

Comment: @Neo i updated code here, but am getting only link is formatting, i need entire paragraph should be formatted

Comment: no it is not working@mjp66

Comment: try to use : TextUtils.htmlEncode()

Comment: try this textView.setText(Html.fromHtml("your text"));

Answer (score 2):

You can do it like this

```
SpannableString contentText = (SpannableString) contentView.getText();
 String htmlEncodedString = Html.toHtml(contentText)
```

Comment: i tried using this method am not able use string, it is showing tohtml (android.text.spanned) in html cannot applied in android like this

Comment: SpannableString contentText = (SpannableString) contentView.getText();
String htmlEncodedString = Html.toHtml(contentText);

Comment: Try using the above given way.

Comment: thanks @Zeeshan   SpannableString contentText = new SpannableString( adding_textjoke.getText());
                sendtext = Html.toHtml(contentText).toString(); this is working

Comment: Getting exception `java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to android.text.SpannableString`

Answer (score 0):

```
SpannableStringBuilder text = (SpannableStringBuilder) contentView.getText();
String htmlEncodedString = Html.toHtml(text);
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.